# What synchronization object shall I use for mutually exclusive access in one thread whose state can be read from another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

The best way to explain this is to show it with a code sample.

I have one worker thread that does some mutually exclusive actions (that may take several seconds to complete) that I enclosed within a named mutex as such:

```
//Thread 1
using (Mutex mtx = new Mutex(false, strGlobalMutexName))
{
    if(mtx.WaitOne())
    {
         //Do processing
    }
}
```

The question I have is how to find out from another thread that `mtx` Mutex was `entered` (or acquired) in my `Thread 1`? And, if it's not possible with a mutex, is there some other synchronization principle in .NET that can allow it?

Comment: After acquiring the first mutex, do something appropriate to let other threads know that you acquired the mutex. Just before relasing it, do something appropriate to let other threads know you're releasing it. That could mean changing the value of a volatile boolean. That could mean setting some variable protected by another mutex. Just code exactly what you want.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yeah, I can use a named event for that. I was hoping to accomplish this with a single synchronization object. There's no way to read the state of my `mtx` from another thread, is there?

Comment: The `Mutex` is very expensive primitive for your case. If you change the state within one thread and want only to read from other threads you can use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Well, the processing part may take many seconds, so I guess whatever CPU cycles I may save by abandoning Mutex will not matter that much.

Comment: I'm curious, can I use `Monitor.TryEnter(mtx)` for my purpose?

Comment: Yes, you can. But, `ReaderWriterLockSlim` is specially invented for `one writer many readers` case.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Well, thanks. I'll look into it.